# Sorting alphanumeric characters

Tags: sorting

I am new to QGIS. The version I am trying to get used to is v3.6. I have been trying to sort this table in map layout but still ending up as displayed in the table below. Need help to sort in ascending order.

[image]

Comment: What you show is neither descending or ascending.

Comment: Please give some more information - what did you try to sort these entries? What field type are the values - string, I guess? If you have combined text and numbers in the same field, it can get problematic to order them - you will probably get an alphabetic order - thus: PRIL 1, PRL 11, PRL 2, PRL 20, PRL 3, PRL 33 and so on. Just the last entry has "APRL" and all others "PRL", is that correct?